# How to get unittest test results on gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci, python-unittest, python-3.7, gitlab-ci-runner

After using gitlab-runner to execute python unittest, testcase fails, but gitlab shows pass.

```
$ python3 test/test_utils.py
test_init (__main__.Test_BslReset) ... ERROR
test_reset_all (__main__.Test_BslReset) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_init (__main__.Test_BslReset)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test_utils.py", line 9, in setUp
    self.bsl_reset = common.utils.BslReset()
  File "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/FgNVsWZq/0/root/hddl-r-sanity/common/utils.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.bsl_reset_src = os.path.join(get_hddl_install_dir(), 'hddl-bsl')
  File "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/FgNVsWZq/0/root/hddl-r-sanity/common/utils.py", line 65, in get_hddl_install_dir
    raise ValueError('Not check EnvVar(HDDL_INSTALL_DIR),Please set it!')
ValueError: Not check EnvVar(HDDL_INSTALL_DIR),Please set it!

======================================================================
ERROR: test_reset_all (__main__.Test_BslReset)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test_utils.py", line 9, in setUp
    self.bsl_reset = common.utils.BslReset()
  File "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/FgNVsWZq/0/root/hddl-r-sanity/common/utils.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.bsl_reset_src = os.path.join(get_hddl_install_dir(), 'hddl-bsl')
  File "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/FgNVsWZq/0/root/hddl-r-sanity/common/utils.py", line 65, in get_hddl_install_dir
    raise ValueError('Not check EnvVar(HDDL_INSTALL_DIR),Please set it!')
ValueError: Not check EnvVar(HDDL_INSTALL_DIR),Please set it!

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=2)
Job succeeded
```

I want to use gitlab-ci on gitlab to execute python unittest, the .gitlab-ci.yml configuration file is as follows:

```
stages:
 - build
 - test

build:
 stage: build
 script:
  - sudo apt-get install python3-pip
  - pip3 install -r requirements_linux.txt
 tags:
  - 'server'
test:
 stage: test
 script:
  - python3 test/test_utils.py
 tags:
  - "server"
```

I think gitlab just judges python3 test/test-utils.py this command is not successful, and did not really get the results in unittest, how to do it?

Comment: It seems that your python code overrides the exit code to 0 (it should be 1). Can you post the code of `test/test-utils.py` ?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to [expose the results of your unit tests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/unit_test_reports.html) in the pipeline and MR pages of GitLab.

If you are using PyTest you need to configure your CI job like this:

```yaml
pytest:
    stage: test
    ...
    before_script:
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
    script:
        - python -m pytest --junitxml=report.xml
    artifacts:
        when: always
        reports:
            junit: report.xml
        expire_in: 2 weeks
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the tests as a module using TextTestRunner, it does not exit with code 1.

You'd want to capture the result and call wasSuccessful() on it like so:

```py
import unittest
from test_app import SomeTestCase

if __name__ == "__main__":
   suite = unittest.TestSuite()
   suite.addTest(SomeTestCase('test_add'))
   result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)

   if result.wasSuccessful():
       exit(0)
   else:
       exit(1)
```

Source: https://code-maven.com/python-unittest-fails-exit-code-0